# Is universe infinite or not?

Tags: universe

What do you guys think of Hawking's last paper "A Smooth Exit from Eternal Inflation?" https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.07702.pdf according to him there's no such thing as infinite multiverses so he concluded there are many universes, although not infinite with nothingness or space outside of them. He even said he's not a fan of the multiverse theory but in Science there should be no favouritism. Do you think the whole universe is really finite, and do you think outside of those multiple universes there is just absolute nothingness outside of them?

Comment: Hi Mohamed. The topic of whether or not the universe is infinite has already been discussed (tl;dr there is no way of knowing). If you are specifically asking about Hawking's paper perhaps to could edit your question to explain what aspects of the paper you are asking about.

Comment: Extending John's comment, we don't actually do paper reviews here, so you'd have to modify the question to ask about a specific aspect of the paper, which would require quoting the relevant section.